# Including parts of different git repositories in a directory

Tags: git, github, repository

I have `n` repositories with content that I would like to make available in a directory of my server. The server directory will be dynamically scanned for content for to work with that content.

However, I would like to keep the repositories which I like to import as they are. I do not want to merge or perform any one-way tasks. The source repositories really should remain independent.

When I `git pull` on my server directory, I'd like to update all those files that I *subscribed* to. Note that it does not have to be `git pull` but you get the idea of what I mean.

This is what it should look like (there are more files and repositories, it's just an example):

```
- github
    - repo 1 with 10 files
    - repo 2 with 5 files
- server
    - content-directory
          - 2 files "subscribed" out of repo 1
          - 1 file "subscribed" out of repo 2
```

Changes on `github`'s repositories should be applied to the server-directory files as soon as I do something like `git pull` in there.

*Is there a simple way of doing this?*

My approach: Create clones of those repositories in `content-directory` but then I would get the whole repo although I only want some files. `.gitignore` prevents from *uploading* but not from *downloading*.

Maybe there already is a good way that I just do not know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no native Git functionality for this, but you can probably get the results you want using [symlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), which are available on POSIX systems but [also on Windows with NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link).

I'll be assuming a Linux system here.

Check your repositories out somewhere outside of your content directory:

```
$ cd /some/directory/repos
$ git checkout https://github.com/user/repo-a.git
$ git checkout https://github.com/user/repo-b.git
$ ls
repo-a/ repo-b/
```

Now, link the files you want from each repository into your server's content directory:

```
$ cd /path/to/server/content/directory
$ ln -s /some/directory/repos/repo-a/file1 .
$ ln -s /some/directory/repos/repo-a/file2 .
$ ln -s /some/directory/repos/repo-b/file1 file1b
```

The files show up in the directory, but if you use a long listing (`-l`) you can see that they're really links to other files:

```
$ ls
file1 file1b file2
$ ls -l
file1 -> /some/directory/repos/repo-a/file1
file1b -> /some/directory/repos/repo-b/file1
file2 -> /some/directory/repos/repo-a/file2
```

Comment: In combination with this solution, you can use [sparse clone](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/495796) to get only the directories you want.